# Different between NOT IN and NOT EXISTS in postgres SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here's my table.
[image: info.student_info table]

When I execute the below query using NOT IN it gives me namal and Ann.

```
SELECT firstname 
FROM info.student_info 
WHERE firstname NOT IN (SELECT firstname 
                        FROM info.student_info 
                        WHERE lastname IS NULL)
```

But when I execute the below query using NOT EXISTS it gives me no rows.

```
SELECT firstname 
FROM info.student_info 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT firstname 
                  FROM info.student_info 
                  WHERE lastname IS NULL)
```

Why is this? I have researched some areas on NOT IN and NOT EXISTS, but couldn't find an answer for this.

Comment: In the second case, the correlated subquery is **not** corelated to the main query; it returns True if there does not exist **any** row with `lastname IS NULL`.

Comment: The usual answer is `NULL`, but your `NOT IN` already filters out `NULL`s. @wildplasser accurately points out the difference.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`NOT IN` is true when value is not in the set returned by the subquery.
`NOT EXISTS` is true when the subquery doesn't return anything.

Comment: Thank you Jakub. It tell's everything!

Answer (score 3):

You have not joined the tables in your `NOT EXISTS` query and that is why, you're not getting any result from your second query.

Your second query would have returned results only in case when the sub-query could not find record at all.

change your query to join on the firstname column of the outer table, and then you might get result.

```
SELECT firstname
FROM info.student_info
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT b.firstname
                  FROM   info.firstname b
                  WHERE  b.lastname IS NULL
                  AND    b.firstname = a.firstname
                 )
```

Disclaimer: Not tested the query

Answer (score 2):

Your `NOT EXISTS` doesn't discriminate on firstname, so the subselect will always return 2 rows.

To do the same thing with NOT EXISTS you need to use the following SQL:

```
SELECT firstname FROM info.student_info 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT firstname f2 FROM info.student_info
    WHERE lastname IS NULL 
      AND f2 = firstname)
```

Comment: Thank you! Honestly, I had an misunderstanding on the IN and EXISTS. I was enlightened with Jakub's answer. Apart from that here the result is same.