# MYSQL Sub-query not working as expected when after OR operator

Tags: mysql, subquery, operators

I am trying to run a query that is working in quite an unexpected way. It's made up of 2 different parts, which work independently, but do not when combined with an OR.

When I run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM testdatabase.test_view AS test
WHERE 
    test.deleted_at IS NULL AND test.a_id IS NULL AND test.lp_id IS NULL
```

I get 14 results.

When I run this other query:

```
SELECT * FROM testdatabase.test_view AS test
WHERE 
    test.deleted_at IS NULL AND test.a_id IS NOT NULL AND test.a_deleted_at IS NOT NULL
AND test.id NOT IN (
    SELECT id FROM testdatabase.test_view
    WHERE a_deleted_at IS NULL AND deleted_at IS NULL AND id IS NOT NULL
```

I get 227 results.

When I combine them both with an OR:

```
SELECT * FROM testdatabase.test_view AS test
WHERE 
    ((test.deleted_at IS NULL AND test.a_id IS NULL AND test.lp_id IS NULL)
    OR
        (test.deleted_at IS NULL AND test.a_id IS NOT NULL AND test.a_deleted_at IS NOT NULL
    AND test.id NOT IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM testdatabase.test_view
        WHERE a_deleted_at IS NULL AND deleted_at IS NULL AND id IS NOT NULL
        ))
    )
```

If everything worked as expected, I should get something between 227 and 227+14 results. That is something between 227 and 241 results.

However, I'm getting 249 results.

Maybe the problem has to do with this part:

```
NOT IN (SELECT id FROM testdatabase.test_view WHERE a_deleted_at IS NULL AND deleted_at IS NULL AND id IS NOT NULL)
```

which for some reason does not work as I expected when combining both parts.

I'm not looking for another way of getting correct results, I already got it to work iwith another approach, but that's not the issue at hand, my problem is that I have no idea why this doesn't work as expected.

What's going on?

- I'm using some unnecessary parentheses, trying to make everything extra-explicit/clear. (I already checked to make sure this had nothing to do with the issue, and as expected, nothing changes).
- I know the `test.deleted_at IS NULL` condition could be simplified, I'm keeping it like this to be extra explicit. (I brought it out of each part of the OR to apply it just once to the whole thing and once more, that changed nothing, as expected).
- I'm not including a broader view of the problem, because it would only create additional doubts and make the issue more complicated. I'm not trying to get it to work; I already did that, I just want to understand why the exact query I posted works as it does and not as I expected.
- I know a NOT EXISTS would help make it work (already did so).
- It is not an issue of how NOT IN handles null cases, I already included an extra condition to tackle that (AND id IS NOT NULL).

Comment: Post the task, not only your attempt to solve. According to [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), especially #5 and #3.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Akina. The thing is, I'm not trying to solve a task. The task has already been solved with a workaround, I'm trying to understand the intricacies of a specific behaviour of MYSQL. Explaining the whole task "behind" this problem, would only add noise to it, since it's way more complex. I could also post the results of my query, showing the table, but I don't see the point of showing a table with over 200 results when they are not important. I believe the relevant fact is that when applying an OR operator the result is larger than the sum of its parts, which it shouldnt.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Thank you for reply @philipxy. I didn't include the whole code, because it would complicate matters A LOT. This query was run on a view, so I would need to include the view and the tables that it was getting it's information from. It's part of a very big project and it's really complicated to isolate the information. That's why I'm asking an "on paper" much simpler question. How can the result of A OR B, give a larger number of results than A + B? As I said previously, I don't want to get it to work. I already did so. I just want to understand the theory of why MYSQL does what it does.

Comment: Your comments do not give reasons to not give a [mre] & otherwise improve your post. One of the reasons it is obligatory is to avoid posting duplicate & overly asker-specific posts & vague posts that are not useful to the site. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) When pinned down to a specific question this will be a faq. PS Social & meta commentary do not belong in posts. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score 0):

The NOT IN operator does not work well with NULL values because it does not match NULL values correctly. Specifically, if the subquery returns any NULL values, the NOT IN operator will not work as expected, and the query may return unexpected results.

In contrast, the NOT EXISTS operator does work well with NULL values because it evaluates to true only if the subquery returns no rows. In other words, if the subquery returns any NULL values, the NOT EXISTS operator will still evaluate to false and not cause unexpected results.

```
SELECT * FROM testdatabase.test_view AS test
WHERE 
   test.deleted_at IS NULL AND (
      test.a_id IS NULL AND test.lp_id IS NULL OR
(
  test.a_id IS NOT NULL AND test.a_deleted_at IS NOT NULL AND
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM testdatabase.test_view AS sub_test
    WHERE sub_test.id = test.id AND
      sub_test.a_deleted_at IS NULL AND sub_test.deleted_at IS NULL AND sub_test.id IS NOT NULL)))
```

[Different between NOT IN and NOT EXISTS in postgres SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426630/different-between-not-in-and-not-exists-in-postgres-sql)

Comment: Thank you for your reply @FitTale. In the problematic part, I already added "AND id IS NOT NULL" in order to tackle the NULL cases you mentioned. So, that shouldn't be causing any problems. Additionally, if that was the issue, when using the query independently, it wouldn't be working correctly either. As I mentioned in the original post, I already managed to get it to work using a NOT EXISTS (there, I found some other weird issues, but that would ask for another post) however, using an alternative does not answer the question as to why the first method does not work as expected :(.